# select all from database with currentdate if currentdate in database is in datetime format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My mysql date is in datetime format which is correct because I also wanted to use the time to show it on my website. Now what I wanted to ask is how to show all records with todays date only.

**MY QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM tblid where datecreated = NOW()
```

but with this format It doesn't retrieve anything from the database.

Here's what my time in my website looks like which is correct

```
2014-09-09 11:30:10
```

and I only wanted to filter using sql query to just show all data with this date

```
2014-09-09
```

which is today's date.
 Is it in my script?
How will I do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`curdate()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) instead if you just want the date:

```
SELECT * FROM tblid where DATE(`datecreated`) = CURDATE()
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tblid where DATE_FORMAT(`datecreated`, '%Y/%m/%d') = CURDATE()
```

Comment: it doesn't retrieve the data also.`SELECT * FROM tblid where datecreated = CURDATE()` take note of the format of my datetime in mysql

Comment: @Dodgeball are you sure its todays date? try my revision

Comment: Found it. I did this one.  `SELECT * FROM tblid WHERE DATE(datecreated) = CURDATE()`

Comment: @Dodgeball okay glad it went your way

Answer (score 0):

```
..WHERE DATE_FORMAT `datecreated` = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y:%m:%d')
```